# hierarchical tree with java and wicket

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, wicket

I am new at wicket. I have a problem needs a solution. I have a data table and it contains "subject codes" like 10,10.1,10.1.2,10.10.1.3,... and also these subject codes have corresponding "subject names". What I need to do is: In my application user enters a subject code as input text area and application returns max 20 correponding subject codes as a list. User chooses one of the codes and application shows this code and it's related name at a hierarchical tree. For instance user chooses 10.1.2, tree shows this selected code as a tree. I was able to list max 20 codes and user choses one of the codes but I could not create the tree. Did anyone do something like that by using wicket?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried DefaultTreeModel of wicket library but I could not create the tree on the screen. I am new at wicket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implementation of the Wicket `TreeTable`:

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/tree/simple

Start of with this example and you will get data on your screen. You can modify it so it suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I looked that link but my createTreeModel() method is null I dont know how to complete it. My problem is that I think.

Comment: You can take a look at the method here in `BaseTreePage.java` of the example. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes you are right there is a createTreeModel() method at there but I am taking my list from data table, in this example strings are sended in a list for known definite list size. Root and leafs are clear. If I try it from a mixed order list, it is a bit complex. I need something without sending strings. I am able to take 20 items from my data list. But I could  not create the tree .My root and leafs are not ordered  in my data table.